# R session aborted - Windows - Large datasets

Tags: r, dplyr, feather

I am trying to merge several databases from various years (2009 to 2018) with about 800,000 observations each into a single database in feather format but every time I try to do this I get an "R session aborted" message

I have already tried to clean the .Rhistory

```
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE)) 
gc()
```

and reinstall the packages I am using (dplyr and feather)

But still the error persists. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Try data.table instead of dplyr. That might help. If that doesn't work, try R command line, not Rstudio. And otherwise try using sqlite.

Comment: What kind of "merge" are you doing, with what kind of code? Is it a join with non-unique keys -- that's one scenario that might generate results too large for your computer to handle.